# How can I make alias for desktop folder on XP?

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, alias, links, junction

I don't want other users save file to system drive, how can I make a direct link of desktop folder to another folder?

Comment: But the Desktop is a part of the system drive?..

Comment: Did you tried to make a link to SYSTEMROOT\Documents And Settings\[User]\Desktop ??

Answer (score 2):

Search for informations on "Folder Redirection".

You can do that using Group Policies or editing the registry:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders

More details here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/242557